# Passing python output to a js function

Tags: javascript, python, parsing, module, js2py

I have a JS function in which i want to pass my python output and return its responce an way to do it

I tried using js2py but didnt get the output

```
import js2py
opt=js2py.run_file("Encrypt.js")
js2py.translate_file("Encrypt.js","py.py")
print(opt)
```

Answer (score 0):

After calling `translate_file`, you need to import the translated file as well:

`add.js`

```js
function add(a, b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

`test.py`

```py
import js2py
js2py.translate_file("add.js", "add.py")
from add import add

print(add.add(1, 2)) # prints 3
```

For more usage examples, you can refer to [Js2Py Github](https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py)